# Are all prop logic wffs sentences? Why aren't there any free variables?

Tags: logic, definition, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

In propositional logic is it correct to say that all wffs are also sentences/statements? Are sentences and statements the same thing?

I also read that sentences are wffs that lack free variables, but this seems more like a first order logic concept. Does this still apply to propositional logic? If so why are all variables considered bound? Just because they're all either true or false and nothing else?

Comment: I would say, in propositional logic, yes, sentences are the same as well formed formulas.

Comment: Free variables are specific of *predicate logic*, where we have quantifiers. And yes, in prop logic propositional variables stay for *sentences*, i.e. expression having a definite truth value (IN A SPECIFIC INTERPRETATION).

Comment: To be precise, we have also [Quantified propositional logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quantification/#ProQua), but it is a type of calculus quite uncommon,

Comment: In [predicate logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic), *sentences* are formulas without free variables, like e.g. $0=1$ and $\forall x (x=x)$. Having no free vars that can assume different values, a sentence has - IN A SPECIFIC INTERPRETATION - a single truth value.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA as opposed to some other kind of interpretation?

Comment: Yes; sentence $\forall x (x \ge 0)$ is TRUE in $\mathbb N$ and is FALSE in $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: I don't think there is a general agreement on the answer to this question. And, *pace* Mauro, quite a lot of people do work in higher order logics (which include quantified propositional logic). Please tell us more about the sources you are reading.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA but then wouldn't we say $\forall x \in \mathbb{Z}, x \geq 0$ or something? Give that context to $x$ instead of just saying $\forall x$?

Comment: @user525966: as per my comment above, please tell us what texts you are reading.

Comment: @RobArthan Sorry thought you were talking to Mauro. I'm reading MSE in general and a book Mauro recommended called Logic and Structure by Dirk van Dalen, but it doesn't really answer most of the questions I have (it also has too many "we're leaving all this to the reader" sections with no way to check your work -- which is maybe fine if you're a student with access to a professor but terrible if you're a self studier).

Comment: If you are self-studying a specific book, maybe it may help if you add to your questions the ref to the page of the book: as you have experienced with previous questions, the terminology of math logi is not so "stable".

Comment: Having said that, in the context of van Dalen's textbook (see page 7) the language of *propositional calculus* has : *propositional symbols* : $p_0, p_1,\ldots$ and *connectives. Thus, propositional symbols are **not** variables.

Comment: As you said, *free* (and *bound*) variables are part of the language of *predicate logic*.

Comment: And see page 5 : "The linguistic entities occurring in [deductive] reasoning are taken to be *sentences*, i.e. entities that express a complete thought, or state of affairs.We call those sentences *declarative*. A common feature of all those declarative sentences is the possibility of assigning them a truth value, *true* or *false*. Some sentences are minimal in the sense that there is no proper part which is also a sentence; others can be taken apart into smaller parts. Conversely, we can build larger sentences from smaller ones by using *connectives*."

Comment: And see page 7 : "In order to provide mathematics with a precise language we will create an artificial, *formal language*, which will lend itself to mathematical treatment. First we will define a language for *propositional logic*, i.e. the logic which deals only with propositions (i.e. *sentences*). Later we will extend our treatment to a logic which also takes properties of individuals into account."

Comment: But stuff like that makes no sense to me especially without elaboration. "They're not variables" why not? I see the phrase "Boolean variables" used all the time.

Comment: "The proposition symbols and $\bot$ stand for the indecomposable propositions,
which we call *atoms*, or *atomic propositions*" Then follows the formation rules (Def.2.1.2) for building "compelx" propositions from atomic ones using connectives (and parenthesis). The members of the set $\text {Prop}$ (called *propositions*) are the *expressions* (finite strings of symbols) produced according to the formation  rules (see also the concept of *formation sequence* : Def.2.14, page 9). They are sometimes called "well-formed formulas" (but van Dalen does **not** use it in he context of prop logic).

Comment: Going on in the exposition (page 56): we have *predicate symbols*, *variables*, *connectives*, etc. If you consider that we can have $0$-ary predicate symbols, we can see (page 57) that $\bot$ is a formula, and also $P_i$ is a formula, if it has "arity" $0$ (i.e. no argument places). But thus, a $0$-arity predicate symbol is a propositional symbol and its interpretation will be either $1$ (TRUE) or $0$ (FALSE). Again we have the def of the set FORM of all formulas (aka well-formed-formulas) and the set SENT of all *sentences* of pred.calc,i.e. formulas with **no** occurrences of free vars.

Comment: You are right: we can call the prop symbols also [propositional variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_variable): different texts, different choices. But the fact still remain that we have consider them as another type of symbols with respect to the variables of predicate logic.